# How to understand "picking out random variables from a distribution"?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

There are always expressions as "$X_1$, $X_2$, ... $X_i$ are i.i.d.(independent and identically distributed) random variables from a distribution".

1. I am confused about $X_i$ these sort of notations. Does the subscripts mean different times we pick out the random variables? Or is the subscripts not important at most of the time?
2. Additionally, if we specify the distribution as exponential/normal/Binomial/... distribution, can the random variables be not i.i.d.? I just cannot imagine how we pick out those random variables from these distributions.

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do you know a practical (in real life) way to generate i.i.d Bernoulli(1/2) random variables?

Comment: Also, can you reduce the use of abbreviations in the question?  I assume i.i.d. is "independent and identically distributed", but this would be a lot easier for most readers to understand without i.i.d. and r.v.s. all over it.

Comment: @BenjaminWang Like tossing a fair coin?

Comment: @gleedadswell Sorry for that! I have edited it.

Comment: Yes, @BenjaminWang 's question was very useful for you to help you think about the answer to your question.  I'm still not clear on exactly what you mean by your question, but maybe answering the question about tossing a coin helps you see how, in practice, you might "pick" values from the distributions.  Your phrasing, "pick out those random variables from these distributions" doesn't really make sense in the way we use the word "random variable".  Maybe you mean "generate numbers from these distributions"?

Comment: Maybe you're confused how to generate numbers from probability distribution functions. This is a fair question (especially for continuous distributions). For this, if you have Uniform$[0,1]$ r.v's, you can use [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) to do so. (Search up YouTube videos if unclear) You may ask how do you generate Uniform$[0,1]$ r.v's? Well, you can toss fair coins to generate binary digits until you have the desired precision. However, in practice, data science packages like `numpy` do these for you for well-known distributions.

Comment: @BenjaminWang Thank you so much! Now I get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not clear on what you are asking, but I think the bot is being a little hard on you by saying "limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer."  It seems to me that you want an explanation of what a random variable **is**. There are plenty of such explanations in textbooks but maybe you are finding those explanations unhelpful.

Your first question is notational.  No, we would not use $X_1, X_2, ...$ to refer to different times we "pick out" values from the random variable (note how I used slightly different wording from you...).  If we had one random variable, $X$, which corresponded to rolling a 6-sided die, then we would typically refer to the individual rolls in a sample using lower case $x$ with subscripts.  So we might have a sample drawn from $X$ consisting of the rolls $\{ x_1 = 3, x_2 = 5, x_3 =1, ...\}$.  If we had multiple random variables, say $X_1$ corresponding to rolling our red 6-sided die, $X_2$ corresponding to rolling our blue 6-sided die, etc. then the notation would get awkward since the (say) 3rd roll in a sample from our blue die would be called something like $x_{2,3}$ or maybe $x_{2_3}$, so maybe we would have been better off naming our random variables something like $R, B, ...$ to avoid double subscripts.  But when we are writing things where we aren't concerned with talking about individual members of samples from our random variables then we might find it convenient to name the random variables $X_1, X_2, ...$ so we can have an arbitrary number of random variables.

Your second question seems to be about finer points of what we mean by "identically distributed".  If we have multiple random variables they could be independent, identically distributed, no matter what distribution we choose.  We could have four, fair, 6-sided dice.  The rolls from them would be represented by four random variables, and since they have the same distribution (equal probability of 1,2,3,4,5,6) they are identically distributed.  We could have a mole of carbon-14 atoms.  The probability distribution for each of their decays to nitrogen-14 is an exponential distribution with a particular time constant.  So this would give us a mole of independent, identically distributed random variables.  But if we had a 6-sided die and a 20-sided die, then the two random variables describing them are not identically distributed, since they have different probability distributions.

Hopefully that clarifies the notation and terminology.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and intuitive examples, which really help me a lot! As I get a better understanding of these concepts, I found that the description in my question was really ambiguous. Sorry for that again!